# static non-member variable, will it be the same variable to all threads in the program?

Tags: c++, static, static-variables

I'm not interested in having a static member cluttering up my header as it is only to be used by a free functions in the cpp body. If I declare a static variable here will it only ever occupy the one address just as for a static member?

Apologies but the myriad uses of static in C++ have left me quite unsure.

I am thinking along the lines of:

```
static Osp::Base::Runtime::Monitor sharedMonitor;
```

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-a-c-program/572550#572550 is a good start point

Comment: @NicolasMartin: So would a static-member be better here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you define a static variable at namespace scope, then there is one instance of that variable, accessible within the translation unit in which it's defined.

Comment: I tried the static member way but keep getting random crashes. All examples I've seen require some sort of definition outside the class declaration, but I don't see how I can do that with this class.

Answer (score 0):

First, the word "static" has two meanings in C++: it can refer to the
keyword `static` (which in turn has different effects according to where
it is used), or it can refer to the lifetime of a variable: **all**
variables defined at namespace have static lifetime.

From what you say, I think you are looking for a variable with static
lifetime, which would not be visible outside the single translation unit
where it appears.  The preferred way of doing this is to define a
variable in an unnamed namespace:

```
namespace {
int myWhatever;     //  No keyword static...
}
```

Class member variables which are declared `static` also have static
lifetime, as do local variables (inside a function) which are declared
`static`.

Such a variable is accessible everywhere after its definition in the
translation unit, but no where else.  It has a single instance, which
comes into being at the start of the program, and lasts for as long as
the program runs.  If it has a constructor, the constructor will be
called before `main` (or when the dynamic object is loaded, if dynamic
linking is used), and it's destructor will be called after `exit` has
been called (or when the dynamic object is unloaded, if dynamic linking
is used).

With regards to threads, C++11 has a storage class specifier
`thread_local`: variables declared with this specifier have one instance
per thread, with a lifetime which is the equivalent of that of the
thread.  It will be initialized (constructed) before first use, and
destructed when the thread exits.  This is something different from
static.